# Saving the distance between a character and every other character in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, iteration

I have a string x, and I want to save the distance/direction between a random character (I'm gonna call it 'z') in the middle and every other character in x and the type of character to which the distance/direction is pointing to in another string. How can I loop through every other char (from left to right, leaving z out) to save the data in a different string without getting an error? Here's an example:

```
x = "vnu4)rhg&3j"

#if the process would be done with the 'h' in x, this other string-variable 'q'
#should be the result:

q = "-6='v',-5='n',-4='u',-3='4',-2=')',-1='r',+1='g',+2='&',+3='3',+4='j'"
```

I use Python 3.7.4

Comment: What you tried so far and where are you facing issues with your approach? Please include this information in the original question

Answer (score 0):

This is just math, subtract the position of "h" in `x` from the actual position, which can be determined by `enumerate` while iteration over the list:

```
x = "vnu4)rhg&3j"
qList = ["%s='%s'" % (i-x.find('h'), x[i]) for (i, j) in enumerate(x)]
print(qList)  # as list
print(','.join(qList))  # as string
```

Output:

```
["-6='v'", "-5='n'", "-4='u'", "-3='4'", "-2=')'", "-1='r'", "0='h'", "1='g'", "2='&'", "3='3'", "4='j'"]
-6='v',-5='n',-4='u',-3='4',-2=')',-1='r',0='h',1='g',2='&',3='3',4='j'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def save_distance(target_string, target_char):
    index_of_target_char = target_string.find(target_char)
    output_string = ""
    for i, char in enumerate(target_string):
        if i == index_of_target_char:
            continue
        else:
            distance = i - index_of_target_char
            if distance > 0:
                output_string = output_string + "+" + str(distance) + "=" + f"'{char}'" + ("," if i < len(target_string) - 1 else "")
            else:
                output_string = output_string + str(distance) + "=" + f"'{char}'" + ("," if i < len(target_string) - 1 else "")
    return output_string
```

output:

```
"-6='v',-5='n',-4='u',-3='4',-2=')',-1='r',+1='g',+2='&',+3='3',+4='j'"
```

Take note that, should there be several occurrences of the target character in the target string, this solution will not work properly. I am not sure whether or not that matters in the problem you are facing.

Answer (score -1):

This should be enough to get you started:

```
x = "vnu4)rhg&3j"

h_ind = x.find('h')
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(f"{x[i]} = {i - h_ind}")
```

`x.find(h)` is getting the index of 'h' in the string and then being taken away from the index of the other chars.

output:

```
v = -6
n = -5
u = -4
4 = -3
) = -2
r = -1
h = 0
g = 1
& = 2
3 = 3
j = 4
```

This now works for:

```
x = "vvnu4)rhg&3j"
```

output:

```
v = -7
v = -6
n = -5
u = -4
4 = -3
) = -2
r = -1
h = 0
g = 1
& = 2
3 = 3
j = 4
```

Comment: your output would be `v=-6 v=-6...` but it should be `v=-7 v=-6...`

Comment: @BSQL: `find` always takes the first occurrence, in case there are repeating characters `find` will always take the first position.